# How can I create plots before creating animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I would like to plot data using multiprocessing and then creating animation with the plotted data. I mean something like this:

```
frames = []

def get_frames()
        ...
        [index, frame] = mp_queue.get()
        frames[index]=frame

def get_frames_process(queue, index, x_vals, y_vals):
    frame = plt.scatter(x_vals[index], y_vals[index])
    queue.put([index, frame])

def animate(frame):
    frames.pop(0)
    plt.plot(frame)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames)
```

Or also, there is a way of use FuncAnimation with multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`FuncAnimation` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation):

> `frames` can be a generator, an iterable, or a number of frames.

I suggest you write a generator function that uses multiprocessing to iterate through your frame calculations. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from multiprocessing import Pool

def calc_fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return 1
    return calc_fib(n-1) + calc_fib(n-2)

class FibonacciAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count
        self.line, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
        self.pool = Pool(8)

    def update(self, n):
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        return self.line,

    def frames(self):
        for n in range(self.count):
            self.xs = range(n)
            self.ys = self.pool.map(calc_fib, self.xs)
            yield

fig = plt.figure()
fib = FibonacciAnimation(30)
plt.xlim(0, fib.count)
plt.ylim(0, 1000000)
plt.title('Fibonacci Animation')
fib_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, fib.update, fib.frames,
                                  interval=50, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I made the Fibonacci calculation deliberately inefficient so you can compare `map` to `self.pool.map` and see the effect of multiprocessing.